# PostgreSQL query rows in json object that contains certain key value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, jsonb

I have this sample table called `tx` that stores information about transactions, and I am using PostgreSQL 10.6.

```sql
# info about my PostgreSQL version
select version()
> PostgreSQL 10.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit
```

It looks like this:

```sql
# create table
create table tx (id bigserial primary key, msg jsonb not null);

# create index on 'type' value of msg column
create index on tx using gin ((msg->'type'));
```

Insert rows into `tx` table

```sql
insert into tx (msg) values
('[{"type": "MsgSend", "value": {"amount": [{"denom": "dollar", "amount": "100"}], "from": "Jeniffer", "to": "James" }}]'),
('[{"type": "MsgSend", "value": {"amount": [{"denom": "dollar", "amount": "30"}], "from": "Jeniffer", "to": "James" }}]'),
('[{"type": "MsgBuy", "value": {"amount": [{"denom": "dollar", "amount": "10"}], "from": "George", "to": "Smith" }}]'),
('[{"type": "MsgSend", "value": {"amount": [{"denom": "dollar", "amount": "60"}], "from": "Jeniffer", "to": "James" }}]');
```

I have read this [Querying JSON (JSONB) data types in PostgreSQL](http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-postgres-json-data-types.html) and searched similar posts and tested with any given examples, but they don't seem to guide me well to solve what I am trying to accomplish, which is to query rows in `json object`, not `json array`

These posts that

- [Check if a Postgres JSON array contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925641/check-if-a-postgres-json-array-contains-a-string)
- [querying json object from table in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841751/querying-json-object-from-table-in-postgresql)
- [PostgreSQL JSON Query with embedded json Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463811/postgresql-json-query-with-embedded-json-object)

How do I go about achieving these queries? I believe if I were to know how to query one, then I would be able to solve the other questions.

1. How do I query data where column `msg` contains where key value of `type` is `MsgSend`?
2. How do I query data where column `msg` contains where key value of `from` is `Jeniffer`?
3. How do I query data where column `msg` contains `MsgSend` and amount is `greater than 50`?

I will be providing any information that may be needed to figure out this question.

Comment: 9.3 is no longer supported, and JSON support has advanced since then.  Use a newer version.

Comment: Why do you have your JSON objects wrapped in gratuitous arrays of length 1?  Can you fix that, or is it non-negotiable?

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for your comments. It is non-negotiable. Looks like Tomer Sela replied below, which was what I needed to know.

Answer (score 3):

The official [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html) contains all you need.

See below queries per your questions:

> 1. How do I query data where column msg contains where key value of type is MsgSend?

```
select * from tx where msg->0->>'type' = 'MsgSend';
```

> 2. How do I query data where column msg contains where key value of from is Jeniffer?

```
select * from tx where msg->0->'value'->>'from' = 'Jeniffer';
```

> 3. How do I query data where column msg contains MsgSend and amount is greater than 50?

```
select * from tx where (msg->0->'value'->'amount'->0->>'amount')::int > 50;
```